# Did Gideon doubt the angelic visitation in judges 6?

Tags: judges

Judges 6:12 NASB

> [12]The angel of the Lord appeared to him and said to him, "The Lord is with you, O valiant warrior."

In the above text Gideon is visited by an angel of Lord then given a sign,but goes on to ask for more signs in the following texts

Judges 6:37 NASB

> [37]behold, I will put a fleece of wool on the threshing floor. If there is dew on the fleece only, and it is dry on all the ground, then I will know that You will deliver Israel through me, as You have spoken

Judges 6:39 NASB

> [39]Then Gideon said to God, "Do not let Your anger burn against me that I may speak once more; please let me make a test once more with the fleece, let it now be dry only on the fleece, and let there be dew on all the ground."

Could this be a sign of diffidence & distrust in God?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a sign of Gideon's lack of confidence in himself, not a distrust of God. Gideon is weak in character and is actually working in hiding because of fear of the Philistines. It is an indication of God's grace and God's determination to work through Gideon that Gideon's tests are allowed. There is no indication that this should be normal practice for believers.